# boolean_mask or sparse dot product in tensorflow

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, neural-network, nlp

tl;dr what is the most efficient way to dynamically choose some entries of a tensor.

I am trying to [implement](https://github.com/borgr/gcn_tf) [syntactic GCN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04826.pdf) in Tensorflow. Basically, I need to have a different weight matrix for every label (lets ignore biases for this question) and choose at each run the relevant entries to use, those would be chosen by a sparse matrix (for each entry there is at most one label in one direction and mostly no edge so not even that).

More concretely, when I have a sparse matrix of labeled edges (zero-one), is it better to use it in a mask, a sparse-dense tensor multiplication or maybe just use normal multiplication (I guess not the latter, but for simplicty use it in the example)

example:

```
    units = 6 # output size 
    x = ops.convert_to_tensor(inputs[0], dtype=self.dtype)
    labeled_edges = ops.convert_to_tensor(inputs[1], dtype=self.dtype)
    edges_shape = labeled_edges.get_shape().as_list()
    labeled_edges = expand_dims(labeled_edges, -2)
    labeled_edges = tile(
        labeled_edges, [1] * (len(edges_shape) - 1) + [units, 1])
    graph_kernel = math_ops.multiply(self.kernel, labeled_edges) # here is the question basically
    outputs = standard_ops.tensordot(x, graph_kernel, [[1], [0]])
    outputs = math_ops.reduce_sum(outputs, [-1])
```

Comment: Just for my curiosity, any particular reason for the extensive use of the non-public API, `ops`, `math_ops`, `standard_ops`, etc.?

Comment: @user1735003 As what I try to create is so general, I thought that if I implement it well enough I can base it on the implementation of general layers (e.g. Dense) and suggest it for tf to use, perhaps I am being too optimistic, but it currently supports (easily) anything Dense supports, as it only a bit of math that is different. Even if not, it will be useful for others as a repository.

Comment: I still don't understand -- to avoid a long off-topic discussion I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50391080/1735003).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your tl;dr question, you can try using either of the following:

- [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) : typical usage is `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params, ids)`. It returns a `Tensor`, which 0-axis entries are a subset of `Tensor` params. The indices of kept entries are defined by `Tensor` ids.
- [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup_sparse) : is the same as `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` but takes `ids` as a `SparseTensor`.

Comment: And how do you make a matrix of 0-1 into the indices? isn't it just better to use boolean_mask in this case?

Comment: To make a matrix of logits you can try `tf.one_hot`