# When to use tensorflow's internal API (e.g. tf.python.ops.*)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In certain circumstances, some would access tensorflow's python operators via the internal API (e.g. operators in `tf.python.ops.*`) rather than their public API counterpart (e.g. in `tf.*`), as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50384894/1735003).

What is the benefit of accessing functions via `tf.python.ops` if they are made accessible in the public API?

Answer (score 0):

I believe generally, it is better to just use the public API (loading time differences if any are probably irrelevant).

First, It is more readable.
Second, internal imports might change more often (especially in Tensorflow which is never backward compatible).

Saying that, the inner API itself is using the inner API, so anything that is written for it is using those imports.

I wait to see other responses to this question, perhaps with more insightful reasons.